# Azure DevOps Build pipline

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile

I am new to AzureDevOps, i am trying to use Azure DevOps for one of my C++ project. My requirements are below.
1: Build C++ and publish to Artifactory(Azure),This i am able to do and binary able to publish in Artifactory.
2: I want to use that Artifactory(Binary file) while building Docker image with help of binary file. But i am unable to achieve in Azure DevOps. Locally i am able to build docker image with binary and running file.

Just As summary i am writing.

I need to create simple release pipeline using the build artifacts from the previous task
● The Release Pipeline should build a Docker image with the following requirements
○ must contain Build artifacts from the build pipeline.

**Please find below code:**

```
trigger:
- master

jobs:
- job: gcctest
  pool:
   vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
  steps:
  - script: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
  - script: g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/boost/asio -I/usr/include/boost -o binary.out main.cpp
          connection.cpp connection_manager.cpp mime_types.cpp reply.cpp request_handler.cpp request_parser.cpp server.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread

  - powershell:
        $commitId= "$env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION"

        $definitionName= "$env:BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME"

        $shortId= $commitId.Substring(1, 8)

        $buildName="$definitionName.$shortId"   

        Write-Host $buildName  

        Write-Output "$buildName">readme.txt

  #       echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=text]$buildName"
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
      contents: '?(*.out|*.txt)'
      targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
        pathToPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        artifactName: result

  - task: Docker@1
    displayName: 'Build using multi-stage'
    inputs:
   containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
   dockerRegistryEndpoint: 'My Container Registry'
     arguments: '--build-arg ARTIFACTS_ENDPOINT=$(ArtifactFeed)'
```

**Docker File:**

````
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libboost-all-dev
COPY .  /app
EXPOSE 80
CMD /app/binary.out 0.0.0.0 80 .```
~
````

**Expected result:**

```
Docker image should build by artifact and able to publish on DockerHub repo.
```